# Can't edge swipe to navigate back a screen

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

iOS 7 apps typically use a left to right edge swipe to go back to the previous screen, the SE app should do the same

### Pages not utilizing edge swipe:

- Tags/Search page
- Site Index Page

Comment: This does work when you're on a question (since that view has a back button), but not many other places.

Comment: Where isn't this working where you want it to?  This should work in most cases.

Comment: @BrianNickel: Of the top of my head: it would be nice to pull up the menu from the edge swipe, but I'll go through the UI and figure where I think it feels broken when I try to edge swipe

Comment: @BrianNickel I updated my question with the 2 pages I saw right now, if I see anymore I'll be sure to add them

Comment: The [tag:android-app] supports a lot more edge swiping, and it's a nice way to get around. I'm slightly frustrated in the [tag:ios-app], partly due to being habituated to the Android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to help you a little bit.  iOS by default disables swiping back when you set a different left bar button item or hide the navigation (which happens in the case of search).  I've reenabled it when search is active.

When you go to a site's index page, you are actually taken to a new root view so navigating back won't be possible without redesigning the app.  We could have swiping open the navigation but that is already possible at any point from the navigation bar.