# Swipe from left to right to reveal menu

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

At the moment to reveal the menu you need to press the icon at the top left hand corner. It would be better to implement a swipe gesture from left to right to reveal the menu too.

Having this gesture would make using the app more pleasing. It just seems easier.

Comment: i think they said this was status-impossible. let me see if i can find the post

Comment: here it is: [Can't edge swipe to navigate back a screen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223653/248072)

Comment: not really a dupe though. the other one was a bit broad, and mostly status-completed everywhere else

Comment: +1. I can swipe from left to write to go back from a specific place to more general. e.g., from a question to a list of questions. It would be logical to show the list of sites (the menu)  on swipe from left to right when  you are at the top level on one of them.

Comment: It seems logical to have it reveal the menu, because in the layout it sits left of the root view. With the new huge phones, edge swiping should be a primary navigation mechanism.